# How does ap fromMaybe compose?

Tags: haskell, monads

There I was, writing a function that takes a value as input, calls a function on that input, and if the result of that is `Just x`, it should return `x`; otherwise, it should return the original input.

In other words, this function (that I didn't know what to call):

```
foo :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
foo f x = fromMaybe x (f x)
```

Since it seems like a general-purpose function, I wondered if it wasn't already defined, so [I asked on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/684418608454352896), and [Chris Allen replied](https://twitter.com/bitemyapp/status/684467784793886720) that it's `ap fromMaybe`.

That sounded promising, so I fired up GHCI and started experimenting:

```
Prelude Control.Monad Data.Maybe> :type ap
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
Prelude Control.Monad Data.Maybe> :type fromMaybe
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
Prelude Control.Monad Data.Maybe> :type ap fromMaybe
ap fromMaybe :: (b -> Maybe b) -> b -> b
```

The type of `ap fromMaybe` certainly looks correct, and a couple of experiments seem to indicate that it has the desired behaviour as well.

But **how does it work?**

The `fromMaybe` function seems clear to me, and in isolation, I think I understand what `ap` does - at least in the context of `Maybe`. When `m` is `Maybe`, it has the type `Maybe (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`.

What I don't understand is how `ap fromMaybe` even compiles. To me, this expression looks like partial application, but I may be getting that wrong. If this is the case, however, I don't understand how the types match up.

The first argument to `ap` is `m (a -> b)`, but `fromMaybe` has the type `a -> Maybe a -> a`. How does that match? Which `Monad` instance does the compiler infer that `m` is? How does `fromMaybe`, which takes two (curried) arguments, turn into a function that takes a single argument?

Can someone help me connect the dots?

Comment: I'm glad you asked because this was driving me crazy too x.x

Comment: By the way, `ap fromMaybe` is obfuscated code that hopefully no one would ever write in a real program.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apologies for laconic and mechanical answer. I don't like cherry-picking things like Applicative or Monad, but I don't know where you're at. This is [not my usual approach to teaching Haskell](http://haskellbook.com/).

First, `ap` is really `(<*>)` under the hood.

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad
Prelude> import Data.Maybe
Prelude> import Control.Applicative
Prelude> :t ap
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
Prelude> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

What does this mean? It means we don't need something as "strong" as Monad to describe what we're doing. Applicative suffices. Functor doesn't, though.

```
Prelude> :info Applicative
class Functor f => Applicative (f :: * -> *) where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude> :info Functor
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Here's `ap`/`(<*>)` with the Maybe Monad/Applicative:

```
Prelude> ap (Just (+1)) (Just 1)
Just 2
Prelude> (<*>) (Just (+1)) (Just 1)
Just 2
```

First thing to figure out is, which instance of the typeclass Applicative are we talking about?

```
Prelude> :t fromMaybe
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

Desugaring fromMaybe's type a bit gives us:

```
(->) a (Maybe a -> a)
```

So the type constructor we're concerned with here is `(->)`. What does GHCi tell us about `(->)` also known as function types?

```
Prelude> :info (->)
data (->) a b   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Prim’
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

Hrm. What about Maybe?

```
Prelude> :info Maybe
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor Maybe -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Applicative Maybe -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

What happened with the use of `(<*>)` for Maybe was this:

```
Prelude> (+1) 1
2
Prelude> (+1) `fmap` Just 1
Just 2
Prelude> Just (+1) <*> Just 1
Just 2
Prelude> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude> let mFmap = fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
Prelude> (+1) `mFmap` Just 1
Just 2
Prelude> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude> let mAp = (<*>) :: Maybe (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
Prelude> :t (+1)
(+1) :: Num a => a -> a
Prelude> :t Just (+1)
Just (+1) :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)
Prelude> Just (+1) `mAp` Just 1
Just 2
```

Okay, what about the function type's Functor and Applicative? One of the tricky parts here is that `(->)` has be to be partially applied *in the type* to be a Functor/Applicative/Monad. So your `f` becomes `(->) a` of the overall `(->) a b` where `a` is an argument type and `b` is the result.

```
Prelude> (fmap (+1) (+2)) 0
3
Prelude> (fmap (+1) (+2)) 0
3
Prelude> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude> let funcMap = fmap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
Prelude> -- f ~ (->) c 
Prelude> (funcMap (+1) (+2)) 0
3

Prelude> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude> let funcAp = (<*>) :: (c -> a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> (c -> b)
Prelude> :t fromMaybe
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
Prelude> :t funcAp fromMaybe
funcAp fromMaybe :: (b -> Maybe b) -> b -> b
Prelude> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
Prelude> :t funcAp const
funcAp const :: (b -> b1) -> b -> b
```

Not guaranteed to be useful. You can tell `funcAp const` isn't interesting just from the type and knowing how parametricity works.

Edit: speaking of compose, the Functor for `(->) a` is just `(.)`. Applicative is that, but with an extra argument. Monad is the Applicative, but with arguments flipped.

Further whuttery: Applicative `<*>` for `(->) a`) is S and `pure` is K of the SKI combinator calculus. (You can derive I from K and S. Actually you can derive any program from K and S.)

```
Prelude> :t pure
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
Prelude> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
Prelude> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
Prelude> let k = pure :: a -> b -> a
Prelude> k 1 2
1
Prelude> const 1 2
1
```

Comment: This answer is neither laconic nor mechanical. It is lively and detailed!

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I particularly found the definitions of `mFmap`, `funcMap` and `funcAp` useful to further my understanding.

Answer (score 21):

But that use of `ap` is *not* in the context of `Maybe`. We're using it with a function, `fromMaybe`, so it's in the context of functions, where

```
ap f g x = f x (g x)
```

Among the various `Monad` instances we have

```
instance Monad ((->) r)
```

so it is

```
ap :: Monad m =>    m  (a       -> b)  ->    m  a  ->    m  b
fromMaybe     ::  r -> (Maybe r -> r)
ap            :: (r -> (a       -> b)) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)   
ap                   f                        g        x :: b
ap  fromMaybe ::                          (r -> a) -> (r -> b)  , a ~ Maybe r , b ~ r
```

because `->` in types associates to the right: `a -> b -> c ~ a -> (b -> c)`. Trying to plug the types together, we can only end up with that definition above.

And with `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, we can write it as `(fromMaybe <*>)`, if you like this kind of graffiti:

```
 #> :t (fromMaybe <*>)
(fromMaybe <*>) :: (r -> Maybe r) -> r -> r
```

---

As is rightfully noted in another answer here, when used with functions, `<*>` is just your good ole' [**S** combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus). We can't very well have function named `S` in Haskell, so `<*>` is just a part of standard repertoire of the point-free style of coding. Monadic bind (more so, flipped), `=<<`, can be even more mysterious, but a pointfree coder just doesn't care and will happily  use it to encode another, similar pattern,

```
(f =<< g) x = f (g x) x
```

in [combinatory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) function calls, mystery or no mystery (`zipWith (-) =<< drop 1` comes to mind).

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to relabel the type arguments, for clarity.

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
fromMaybe :: c -> Maybe c -> c
```

> Which Monad instance does the compiler infer that m is?

`((->) r)` is a `Monad`. This is all functions that have type `r` as their argument, for some *specific* `r`.

So in the type:

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

`m` ~ `(c ->)`, `a` ~ `Maybe c` and `b` ~ `c`.

The return type, `m a -> m b`, expands to `(c -> Maybe c) -> c -> c` - which is the type of `ap fromMaybe`.

Answer (score 6):

The monad you are looking for is `(->) r` or `r -> _` if you prefer infix syntax.

Then the signature of `ap` expands to:

```
 m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b =
 (r -> (a -> b)) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b = -- now we use the signature of fromMaybe 
 (b -> (Maybe b -> b)) -> (b -> Maybe b) -> b -> b
```

Now if you consider `ap fromMaybe` as a partially applied function and  voila you get the desired result.